# Quarkus startup error: "multiple (but same) scope type annotations" in dependency

Tags: quarkus

Does anyone have any idea why this error is thrown when starting up quarkus?
(Multi module maven project. Each module has a Jandex-Index generated through the jandex maven plugin.)

The error occurred after updating the **quarkus-universe-bom** dependency from version **1.2.1.Final** to **1.3.1.Final**. Using 1.3.0.Final leads to the same result.

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException:
Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#registerBeans threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: Producer method io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource createDataSource_4c279770c59fa93dcf179ab15a1363f01f14f595() declares
multiple scope type annotations: javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped, javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.multipleScopesFound(Beans.java:363)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.createProducerMethod(Beans.java:223)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.findBeans(BeanDeployment.java:763)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.registerBeans(BeanDeployment.java:206)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.registerBeans(BeanProcessor.java:122)
        at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.registerBeans(ArcProcessor.java:262)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:938)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:273)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2027)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1551)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1442)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

Comment: This is weird. Are you using multiple datasources? Do you have several datasources with the same name somehow in your application.properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to track down the issue. Thanks @[Guillaume Smet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043585/guillaume-smet) for pointing me in the right direction!

I used the following datasource settings:

```
# Datasource
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.url=${DATASOURCE_CONNECTION_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apprds?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8}
quarkus.datasource.transactions=xa
quarkus.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource
quarkus.datasource.username=${DATASOURCE_USERNAME:root}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:admin}
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.charset=UTF-8
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=false
```

Not knowing that the first line (i know it is completely redundant at that point) was not only redundant but also causing the issue.
Simply removing

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
```

solved the issue.

As is said, the datasource is completely specified anyways.

My assumption was, that the additional driver specification and so on would just overwrite any defaults provided by the "db-kind" option and that they could live together.
The documentation at https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource is written in a way that led me start with that "db-kind" option. I later on added the additional configuration entries for, for example, the driver and that worked fine in Quarkus 1.2.1.Final.

If that should clearly not be supported, than the documentation might just point that out at some point. I at least can not find a statement for that right now..